# Django - user profile :UNIQUE constraint failed: main_userprofile.user_id

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to build profile model for my existing user model .

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True,upload_to='media_file/avatar/')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='profile',unique=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    birthday = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs["instance"]
        if kwargs["created"]:
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
            user_profile.save()
    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)

    def __str__(self):
       return  self.user.username
```

so i build forms.py to :

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
 birthday = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)

 class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = "__all__"
    exclude =["user"]
```

and i wrote my views.py like this :

```
def profile_form_update(request):
    if request.method =="GET":
        form = UserProfileForm()
        return render(request,"profile_form.html",{"form":form})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        instance = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
        form =UserProfileForm (request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
        context = {
           "form":form,
           "instance": instance,}
    return render(request, "profile_form.html", context)
```

first this is working ,when i make profile in django admin panel .and when I'm trying to load the existing form ,form renders with content that stored in database.when any changes to form that comes with an error:

```
IntegrityError at /profile/update/
UNIQUE constraint failed: main_userprofile.user_id
```

i know somehow my problem is with existing data stored in user models.and i did some google and someone said :

> You are telling UserProfiles that the UserProfiles.u_id is unique, it's not (blanks/null). So you're getting the error. You may want to consider changing u_id to be a AutoField primary_key. And then connect them using models.ForeignKey('UserBase')

Comment: Just remove the `unique` param. A one to one field is just that so you don't need it.

Comment: I did that.when im rendering the form : page _404 :not found

Comment: Don't forget to migrate after the change. When do you get the error?? Is it when you are creating a new one or when you are editing the already created userprofile?

Comment: You'll get a 404 if the user is not logged in, or if a profile does not exist for that user. You should use the `login_required` decorator for your view.

Comment: Change `unique` to `blank` if it should just pass the form. Add `null` if you want it not to be mandatory at all.

Comment: @zaidfazil no,when the user created and i want to update the existing userprofile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this in view, you need to pass the instance to the form inorder to update the same,

```
def profile_form_update(request):
    instance = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=instance)
    context = {
       "form":form,
       "instance": instance,}
    return render(request, "profile_form.html", context)
```

Comment: i did that but it comes with this error :local variable 'form' referenced before assignment .and when i comment the requesr.post in the second line error is :user has no "profile" object

Comment: tnx problem solved .i tried before this but in instance i didnt put user = request.user